# How to open dynamically a new page in Django

Tags: python, django

I have made a Django application to show a list of clustered news articles. I want in the first page to show just a three of articles, and if the user wants to show them all, he can click the "See the real coverage" link and see the overall list of the articles (as GoogleNews functions). In the main page, I have the list of articles in a variable called ***lista***. And I want to publish only the first three elements in the main page, and I want to transfer the list of articles in the the new page which, let's, I call ***theme***. I add the ***theme*** function in the views.py file as:

```
def theme(request,argument):
    lista=argument
    return render(request,'theme.html', locals())
```

And the ***main.html*** code where i call the theme function is as follows:

```
<a href="{% url "mysite.views.theme" argument=lista %} target="_blank">
```

or I try:

```
<a href="{% url "mysite.views.theme" lista %} target="_blank">
```

The **urls.py** code is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^main/$', main),
    ('^all/$', tegjitha),
    ('^(sport)/$', gen),
    ('^(teknologji)/$', gen),
    ('^(showbiz)/$', gen),
    ('^(bota)/$', gen),
    ('^(ekonomi)/$', gen),
    ('^(kulture)/$', gen),
    ('^(theme)/$', theme),
```

It gives me: NoReverseMatch at /main/ error.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have the list of articles in a variable called lista"? A list of article ids? A list of article objects? Besides that, how do *you* think the template code should behave? I mean how would the resulting URL even look like?

Comment: Lista is a list of lists, where every element stores info about a single article: title, source, link... The result should look exactly as Google News: https://news.google.com/. In this page, when the link "See realtime coverage" is clicked, a new page opens with the list of all article talknig about the same topic is shown. So, I have this list in the "main" template, it functions OK, and I want this list of articles to "transfer" somehow in the new page (called "theme"), aiming not to recreate from the beginning the list. I am trying to call a function theme, with argument "lista"

Comment: the idea is fine, i believe that the easy way to do it is to use the rss method with the feedparser

Comment: I have finished the feedparser part, as I said the "main" page (template) functions great. I just want to add this new feature, to give the extended list of similar articles in a new page. In the "main" page only the short list of articles is shown (first two or three artciles). See news.google.com. With the line "<a href="{% url "mysite.views.theme" lista %} target="_blank">" I try to "transfer" this list in the new page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to realize the approach you are trying to take will not work. All that the `url` template tag does is to produce a simple string - an URL for a particular resource. So the result of the tag might be a string like "/post", "/post/24" etc. And that's it. The function doesn't do anything besides producing the URL string, and there is no place for a list of complex python objects in a simple web URL.

You need to also realize that the web, on the most basic level, is stateless. You can not just pass python objects between requests, because each requests is completely separate. You can simulate keeping state between requests using [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/), but I don't think this is the right tool in this particular case.

What you should do instead is to have a unique identifier for each list and pass the identifier in the URLs (in opposite to passing a whole list in an URL). You would then use the identifier in your view, to retrieve the list again, and display the result.

Comment: I am a beginner with Django and web development in general. I was hoping that there is a way to transfer data among different pages. Somewhere the keyword "namespaces" was mentioned and I thought that maybe someone can instruct me ine this direction

Comment: That is not how HTTP works. Every page request is separate. You should keep your data in a database and retrieve it when the particular resource is requested.

Comment: Is there any way that this list can be cashed in RAM?

Comment: You can use Django's session facilities that I linked above. If you save something to a session, next time the same user requests a page you will have access to the object. I feel strongly that is not the right solution for your problem, but this is the closes thing to the mental model you insist on keeping.

Comment: I solved the problem saving the list to the memory using the module pickle. Thank you @LudwikTrammer that changed my mind to memorize everything temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

you need to direct your urls.py as absolute strings just like the url tag in the template. So main would look like this:

```
('^main/$', 'mysite.views.main'),
```

You can also define at the top the path to your patterns:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('mysite.views',
    ('^main/$', 'main'),
    … etc
```

But notice you still need to reference it as a string

Comment: But the "main" page functions OK, I have problem with the "theme" page

Comment: No reverse match at /main/ tells me you have a problem with the main URL in your urls.py (also, you do)

Comment: It follows with "Reverse for 'mysite.views.theme' with arguments... I think I have problems with with "theme" url

Comment: The error says differently. Maybe it's something in the theme template, a bad link to the main URL perhaps?

Comment: Yes, this is the part that I can not configure. This new page (template) can not be called directly from the browser, it must be called dynamically from the main page (template) with an dynamic argument which is this list of articles. I don't know how to properly set up ('^(theme)/$', theme)...